# How to dynamically add column names in a select statement (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

My table contains a `CLOB` field which can have a length of more than 32767 bytes or characters. This would mean that, if I want to extract all the characters from this `CLOB` field, I have to split the `CLOB` into chunks and pass each chunk as a different column in a `SELECT` query statement.

So I have this query:

```
SELECT dbms_lob.Substr(clob_field, dbms_lob.Getlength(clob_field), 1) AS data
FROM   some_table
```

This won't work if `clob_field` is too large. My idea is to make chunks of 2000 in length and, for each chunk, to add a column in the `SELECT` statement.

Idea concept:

```
var a = 1
var b = 2000
chunkAmountList = 1+(dbms_lob.Getlength(clob_field) mod 2000)
statement = "SELECT "

BEGIN
for chunk in chunkAmountList
    statement = statement + "dbms_lob.Substr(clob_field, b, a) as data"
    a = a + 2000
    b = b + 2000
endloop
END

statement = statement + "FROM some_table"
statement.execute()
```

This will result in different columns with the same name (which is what I want). So if clob_field has a length of 5000, I would want this as a result:

```
data                  data                   data
----                  ----                   ----
"first 2000 chars"    "second 2000 chars"    "last 1000 chars"
```

I want to do this in oracle, but don't know how to. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would use 2048 characters instead of 2000; it fits more neatly in to 32767.  It's also more normal to have a new row for each "piece" of the string.  Then you can do it with a join instead of dynamic SQL.  *(Create a table of 16 rows with the values 1 to 16 in it.  Join against that and select out the row's id and the `n`th 2048 characters.)*  Then you also only need to return rows with values, instead of potentially returning 16 fields where some of them are empty.  Is there a reason that it MUST be split in to multiple *fields*?

Comment: What is the purpose of you extracting all the data? Is someone definitely going to read it? What method are they using to access the database? A rendered site of some description, or are they reading it directly in something like SQL*Plus.

Comment: Are you aware that a CLOB may have contain several TBytes? Number ob columns must not exceed 1000, this would not fit.

Comment: The columns of your `select` statement need to have different names.  It is possible that your client would add a `_1` and `_2` to the second and third `data` columns to force uniqueness but I wouldn't count on that.  Why do you believe that you need the data in chunks?  There aren't a whole lot of frameworks that can't handle just reading data from a LOB so the premise of the question sounds odd.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to break up a large object into multiple rows, not that you can't make it into multiple columns, but if you do, you frequently end up with more columns than you need, or may find yourself exceeding the maximum number of allowed columns.

In creating a solution for this you do need to understand the parameters to the `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(lob, size, index)`. The second parameter is the size of the substr you want to return so it's value should remain fixed, and you would only need to increment the index.

Here's one possible implementation, for demonstration purposes, I'm using a size of 5 but you can easily replace it with a larger size:

```
WITH sample_data( id, lob ) AS (
   SELECT 1
        , 'this is a test'
     FROM dual
), r( id, lob, len, seq, str ) AS (
   SELECT 1
        , lob
        , dbms_lob.getlength( lob )
        , 1
        , dbms_lob.substr( lob, 5, 1 )
     FROM sample_data
    UNION ALL
   SELECT id
        , lob
        , len
        , seq + 1
        , dbms_lob.substr( lob, 5, 1 + 5 * seq )
     FROM r
    WHERE 1 + 5 * seq < len
)
 SELECT * FROM r;

        ID LOB                   LEN        SEQ STR      
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 this is a test         14          1 this      
         1 this is a test         14          2 is a      
         1 this is a test         14          3 test
```

If you really want multiple columns instead of multiple rows, you can pivot the above results by changing the last line:

```
 SELECT * FROM r PIVOT (max(str) str for seq in (1, 2, 3));

        ID LOB                   LEN 1_STR    2_STR    3_STR  
---------- -------------- ---------- -------- -------- --------
         1 this is a test         14 this     is a     test
```

You can add as many numbers to the `seq in (...)` clause as you need:

```
 SELECT * FROM r PIVOT (max(str) str for seq in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

        ID LOB                   LEN 1_STR    2_STR    3_STR    4_STR    5_STR    6_STR  
---------- -------------- ---------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
         1 this is a test         14 this     is a     test
```